# CSS does not load in Laravel 8 + Jetstream on XAMPP

Tags: laravel, xampp, laravel-jetstream

I am learning Laravel and using Laravel 8 and Jetstream. While testing the application on XAMPP, the css does not load on login/register pages. The css link points to localhost/app/css location. It works fine if i use `php artisan serve` command but does not work on XAMPP. How do i correct the css pointer so that it will work with both the `php artisan serve` command as well as XAMPP?

Comment: have you place them in /public/css ?

Comment: @Abilogos As far as i understand, these assets are automatically published to the public directory after running npm run dev. Also, the css loads properly if i execute it with the php artisan serve command. The problem only exists with XAMPP as the link points to localhost/css/app.css whereas for XAMPP it should point to localhost/myapp/public/css/app.css.

Comment: "_it should point to localhost/myapp/public/css/app.css_" The `public` folder should not show up in the URL, it should be the DocumentRoot. Best would be to set up a vhost on Apache, like `project1.local` and point it to your projects public folder. Make sure your `APP_URL` in `.env` is set correctly

Comment: Try `npm install` and `npm run dev`. I had a similiar issue and solved it by this 2 commands.

Comment: @brombeer Thank you very much! Setting up a vhost solved the problem.

Comment: i have the same problem... i've changed the .env APP_URL from http://localhost to http://localhost/public and httpd-vhost.conf from DocumentRoot "htdocs/PROJECT/pos" to DocumentRoot "htdocs/PROJECT/pos/public with no luck... did i miss something?"

Answer (score 8):

in public\mix-manifest.json, change:

```
"/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
"/css/app.css": "/css/app.css"
```

to

```
"/js/app.js": "js/app.js",
"/css/app.css": "css/app.css"
```

this method works for me, plus it works with both XAMPP and artisan serve.

Comment: for some reason, every time I go to another page or rerun the project, it automatically puts the "/" again. so this was just a temporary solution for me. changing mix with asset as suggested below, worked for me

Answer (score 7):

In **resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php**, change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```

To:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```

This will be work in wamp or xampp.

Comment: This worked for mine.. tnx

Answer (score 6):

for me i comment this :

```
 {{--  @vite(['css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])  --}}
```

& add this code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
 <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Comment: This worked for me when I applied it on both app.blade.php and guest.blade.php. thank you so much!

Comment: tnx my code was missing this for some reason :/

Answer (score 1):

if u change in **public\mix-manifest.json** file

```
"/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
"/css/app.css": "/css/app.css"
```

to

```
"/js/app.js": "js/app.js",
"/css/app.css": "css/app.css"
```

it not work on file: */user/profile* , for this u need ../

so u must do second option, but don't forget to change .js file also !
so in: **resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php** chage

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

and also don't forget to do same in file: **resources\views\layouts\guest.blade.php** chage

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple, you have to go to the **path: YOUR PROJECT/resources/views/layouts**, here you have to add these 2 lines in both files **"app.blade.php"** and **"guest.blade.php"**

incorrect

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

**Right:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

NOTE: If you don't have any lines, you have to add them.

Comment: It might help to specify the change from `mix` to `asset`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem,
you just have to install Laravel Breeze

The first step, run the code below in the terminal

```
composer require laravel/breeze:1.9.2
```

Second step

```
php artisan breeze:install
```

Third step

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

Fourth step

```
php artisan migrate
```

Notes:
Because you are using Laravel 8, when installing Laravel Breeze I recommend using version <1.9 (and below)

if you are using Laravel 9, just run

```
composer require laravel/breeze
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code layouts/guest.blade.php file

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
      
  
      <!-- Scripts -->
      <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
or this


WITH


in
resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php
resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php

will work for both jetstram and breze if styling is not apear

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).